# $(\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_i)^t$: A Generalization on Term Cardinality of Multinomials

Tags: calculus, polynomials, summation

I'm asked to compute the number of terms in the expansion of the expression below:
$$(w+x+y+z)^{10}$$

What is meant by "terms"? How can this be generalized so that we can find something like this:
$$(\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_i)^t$$

Comment: I get $286$... Is that right?

Comment: Describe how you get 286 (-:

Comment: I get $286$ also.

Comment: I get $1716$. Is that right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem To be honest, I got $286$ by copying the "copyable plaintext" from what Wolfram found the expansion to be, then used the find-replace feature in Word to replace $+$'s with $*$'s and it said "Word has completed its search of the document and has made $285$ replacements," so that means there are $286$ as the pattern goes $()+(): 1\implies 2$, $()+()+(): 2\implies 3$, and so on...

Comment: I used the Multinomial Theorem to get the latter answer though...

Comment: Haha, that is clever, but that should only be used as a tool to verify your answers.  See @AndréNicolas's answer for reference to Stars and Bars method. As he noted, that is exactly what you need (-:

Answer (score 1):

If you expand this expression, you get a sum of products of variables. the summands are the terms.

Comment: Yes, but I mean in the final expansion when I "simplify" the resulting expression, then am I to count then or when it's all strewn about?

Comment: You sum the terms until you can't sum them anymore. Take $$(a+b)^{2}$$ as an example. You end up with 4 terms when you start expanding, but after you add the like terms, you end up with 3.

Comment: I got $286$, but what's the method?

Comment: I get $1716$ now is that good then?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably they mean that for example $(x+y)^2$ has three terms, and $(x+y)^3$ has $4$. We multiply out blindly, and then gather expressions involving the same power of $w$, $x$, $y$. and $z$ together.

Note that a term has shape $Cw^ax^by^cz^d$, where $a, b.c.d$ are non-negative integers whose sum is $10$, and $C$ is a multinomial coefficient. So we want to find the number of solutions of $a+b+c+d=10$ in non-negative integers.

To find how many choices there are for $(a.b.c.d)$ is a standard combinatorial problem, solved by the method sometimes called *Stars and Bars*. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) on this is pretty good.

We are not writing down the explicit formula in the hope you will go to the article.

Problems involving Stars and Bars have also been repeatedly discussed on MSE.

The solution for $4$ and $10$ generalized readily to $n$ and $t$.

Answer (score 0):

By terms they mean all combinations of
$$
w^ix^jy^kz^t \qquad (i,j,k,t\in\mathbb{Z})
$$
That exist when you foil out the complete polynomial. An easy way to get a pattern going would be to check out what happens when the exponent is $1,2,3$ (instead of $10$). From there, see if you can get a general expression based upon the number of variables ($4$) and the exponent ($10$).